# An issue occurred while starting sonarqube with custom java maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-plugin

I am creating a custom sonarqube java plugin. After adding the plugin jar file inside ../extensions/plugins folder, I tried to start sonarqube in my device. But it is showing the following issues:

```
Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.server.rule.RegisterRules': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonarsource/analyzer/commons/RuleMetadataLoader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:187)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:80)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.access$001(PlatformLevelStartup.java:55)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:127)
    at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:45)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:124)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.executeStartupTasks(PlatformImpl.java:183)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(PlatformImpl.java:344)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl$1.doRun(PlatformImpl.java:107)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl$AutoStarterRunnable.run(PlatformImpl.java:328)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonarsource/analyzer/commons/RuleMetadataLoader
    at com.plugins.sonar.java.SonarqubeJavaRulesDefinition.define(SonarqubeJavaRulesDefinition.java:44)
    at org.sonar.server.rule.RuleDefinitionsLoader.load(RuleDefinitionsLoader.java:56)
    at org.sonar.server.rule.RegisterRules.start(RegisterRules.java:125)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(StartableBeanPostProcessor.java:33)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonarsource.analyzer.commons.RuleMetadataLoader
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
```

The line of code as mentioned in logs, (SonarqubeJavaRulesDefinition.java:44), is the following:
`RuleMetadataLoader ruleMetadataLoader = new RuleMetadataLoader(RULES_BASE_PATH, runtime);`

The following is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sonar.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>static-java-code-analysis</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>StaticJavaCodeAnalysis</name>
  
  <description>It defines the rules that detect energy smells in different loop types in java</description>
  <packaging>sonar-plugin</packaging>
  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    
    <!-- <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target> -->
    <sonarqube.version>9.4.0.54424</sonarqube.version>
    <sonar.organization>ramgrg</sonar.organization>
    <sonar.host.url>https://sonarcloud.io</sonar.host.url>
    <sonarjava.version>7.15.0.30507</sonarjava.version> 
    <sonar.skipDependenciesPackaging>true</sonar.skipDependenciesPackaging>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
       <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.23.1</version>
     </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
         <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
         <version>${sonarqube.version}</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.sonarsource.analyzer-commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>sonar-analyzer-commons</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.0.1111</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
       <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api-impl</artifactId>
       <version>9.7.1.62043</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
       <artifactId>sonar-java-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${sonarjava.version}</version>
       <type>sonar-plugin</type>
       <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
       <artifactId>java-checks-testkit</artifactId>
       <version>${sonarjava.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.0</version>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</groupId>
             <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>1.21.0.505</version>
             <extensions>true</extensions>
             <configuration>
                <pluginKey>staticjavacode</pluginKey>
                <pluginName>${project.name}</pluginName>
                <pluginClass>com.sonar.java.SonarqubeJavaplugin</pluginClass>
                <sonarLintSupported>true</sonarLintSupported>
             <!--   <skipDependenciesPackaging>true</skipDependenciesPackaging> -->
                <sonarQubeMinVersion>${sonarqube.version}</sonarQubeMinVersion>
                <requirePlugins>java:${sonarjava.version}</requirePlugins>   
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonarsource/analyzer/commons/RuleMetadataLoader`

That means the required class is not found in the classpath during runtime.

In your case, your custom SonarQube plugin is missing a dependency on the `sonar-analyzer-commons` library.
Try and add the dependency ([`org.sonarsource.analyzer-commons » sonar-analyzer-commons`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.analyzer-commons/sonar-analyzer-commons)) to your custom plugin's `pom.xml` file.

```xml
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.analyzer.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-analyzer-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0.1358</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version that matches your SonarQube version -->
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

That library does include [`RuleMetadataLoader.java`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-analyzer-commons/blob/master/commons/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/analyzer/commons/RuleMetadataLoader.java).

---

The [OP RamGrg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3202325/ramgrg) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76229040/an-issue-occurred-while-starting-sonarqube-with-custom-java-maven-plugin/76249080#comment134472653_76249080):

> I have these inside `<dependencyManagement> <dependencies>....</dependencies></dependencyManagement>`.

And that the root cause of your issue.
Let's clarify the differences between `<dependencies>` and `<dependencyManagement>`:

1. `<dependencies>`: This section is used to declare the dependencies that your project needs. The libraries specified here will be included in the classpath during the build process.
2. `<dependencyManagement>`: This section is used to manage the versions of dependencies in a multimodule project. When you declare dependencies inside the `<dependencyManagement>` tag, **you are not actually including them in your project**. Instead, you're specifying the versions that should be used if the project or its submodules were to include those dependencies.
   It's a way to ensure that all submodules use the same version of a dependency, thereby avoiding potential conflicts.

The issue in your case is likely due to the fact that the `sonar-analyzer-commons` dependency is declared inside `<dependencyManagement>`, but not in `<dependencies>`. This means that the dependency isn't actually being included in your build, leading to the `NoClassDefFoundError` you're seeing.

To resolve this, you should move the `sonar-analyzer-commons` dependency from `<dependencyManagement>` to `<dependencies>`.
Here's how you can do this:

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- other dependencies can be managed here, for instance: -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.0.54424</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- declare other managed dependencies here... -->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Here is where you should declare sonar-analyzer-commons dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.analyzer.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-analyzer-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.1111</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- declare other direct dependencies here... -->
    </dependencies>
    ...
</project>
```

In this `pom.xml`, the `sonar-analyzer-commons` dependency is declared outside the `<dependencyManagement>` section, meaning it will be included in the classpath during the build.

In the `<dependencyManagement>` section, you're managing the version of `sonar-plugin-api` (and possibly other dependencies) to ensure that all submodules (if any) use the same version. But these dependencies won't be included in the classpath unless they're also declared in the `<dependencies>` section.

---

Your `pom.xml` seems OK with respect to the `sonar-analyzer-commons` dependency. It is declared in the `<dependencies>` section, so it should be included in the classpath during the build. You might want to double-check your dependency versions to ensure compatibility, however.

Here's an updated version of your `pom.xml`, with a potentially compatible `sonar-analyzer-commons` version. However, this is just a guess, since compatibility often involves more than one dependency. You might need to check the compatibility with other dependencies as well.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <!-- ... rest of your pom.xml ... -->
  <dependencies>
    <!-- ... rest of your dependencies ... -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.sonarsource.analyzer.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-analyzer-commons</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0.1111</version> <!-- Ensure this version is compatible with your SonarQube version -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... rest of your dependencies ... -->
  </dependencies>
  <!-- ... rest of your pom.xml ... -->
</project>
```

In the updated version, I only changed the comment for the `sonar-analyzer-commons` dependency to highlight the need for compatibility with your SonarQube version.

If you're still encountering the same issue, the problem might not be with the `pom.xml`. It could be related to the way your custom plugin is interacting with the SonarQube API, or it might be a problem with the SonarQube setup itself.

Comment: I already have this dependency with 2.1.0.1111 version. Apart from this, I am using 9.4.0.54424 sonarqube version,  and 7.15.0.30507 sonarjava version in my pom.xml file.

Comment: @RamGrg Did you declare this in the [`<dependencies>` section or the `<dependencyManagement> section`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependencymanagement-vs-dependencies-tags) of your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I have these inside <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>....</dependencies></dependencyManagement>.

Comment: @RamGrg OK, that explains your error then. I have edited the answer to detail why.

Comment: My project doesn't have multiple modules. So I tried by putting all dependencies inside <dependencies> .. </dependencies>. But the issue persists.

Comment: @RamGrg Can you edit your question with the content of your current pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

check $sonarqube_home/logs to get more info on this! I am sure you have tried common scenarios. Sometime I also delete contents of sonarqube/data in order to make sure any cached configuration is deleted (please take a backup before)--requires stopping of sq server. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

following both dependencies are not compatible:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.analyzer-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-analyzer-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.1111</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api-impl</artifactId>
    <version>9.7.1.62043</version>
</dependency>
```

I see when I import your pom that the class you are getting the NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonarsource/analyzer/commons/RuleMetadataLoader
that this version of the artifact (2.1.0.1111) is not compatible with the org.sonarsource.sonarqube.sonar-plugin-api:sonar-plugin-api-9.4.0.54424.jar (version 9.4.0.54424)
for example one of the methods in RuleMetadataLoader (org.sonarsource.analyzer.commons.RuleMetadataLoader#addOwaspAsvs) use org.sonar.api.server.rule.RulesDefinition.NewRule (org.sonar.api.server.rule.RulesDefinition.NewRule is present in sonar-plugin-api-9.4.0.54424.jar but the method org.sonar.api.server.rule.RulesDefinition.NewRule.addOwaspAsvs is only present from version 9.9...).

As RuleMetadataLoader use non-existing method of already loaded classes, the initialization of the class RuleMetadataLoader failed and you get this error.

You must upgrade your sonar-plugin-api to at least 9.9 or downgrade your sonar-analyzer-commons to a lower version.